# Is there (currently) a way to install the Xbox One controller firmware updates from my PC?

Tags: pc, controllers, xbox-one

I am one of the many who have purchased an Xbox One controller who doesn't actually own an Xbox One.  I purchased it with the intent that when the PC drivers came out, I'd use it on my PC.  Specifically, I purchased the Titanfall themed controller.  Well, the drivers have been out for some time now and it works fine.

However, since the Xbox has been out, there had been a number of firmware updates for the controllers.  AFAIK, there's one to be able to use the headset adapter (not a big deal) and one that increases the sensitivity of the sticks (somewhat a big deal).  As far as I know, it's only possible to get those firmware updates through an actual Xbox One.  It just bugs me that I can't get the latest updates.

**Is there a way to install any of these firmware updates from my PC when I don't have access to a physical Xbox One?**

As far as I can tell, we only received drivers so the controllers can communicate with the OS.  There isn't anything included that facilitates any updates to the firmware.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like it's possible to update the firmware from a Windows PC... provided it's Windows 10.

You'll need to get the Xbox Accessories app from the Windows Store.  With it installed, if you connect your Xbox One Controller and run the app, you might be presented with an option to "Upgrade Controller" (I forgot the exact wording).  I'm assuming it's updating the firmware to the current version.

I have no way to confirm this now but you *might* be able to try this on a Windows 8/8.1 machine since it's just a "modern" app. But don't get your hopes up.

Answer (score 1):

i can confirm that at this current stage microsoft aren't releasing the firmware through PC but at E3 they did say they were planning to bring this option to PC as well. currently the only ways to install firmware are shown in this post.

http://www.7tutorials.com/how-update-firmware-your-xbox-one-controller-headset

Im sorry its not the answer you were looking for, i am in the same boat as you, i am not a console gamer but there are some games that play better with a controller on the pc.

Comment: It seems like it's possible now. Though you might need to have Windows 10 to update it.